# Cannot Use JSON.stringify in aaData for Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

I am using jquery DataTables to bind my JSON data to the Table, however when I specify the JSON object to the 'aaData' option of the DataTable, it throws me this error:

"DataTables warning (table id = 'tblReceipt'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0"

My JSON object looks like this:

```
var r = [
    { "Vid": "1", "Receiptno": "AFL123", "Type": "3", "Branch": "AFL", "Date": "23/11/2013" },
    { "Vid": "2", "Receiptno": "AFL124", "Type": "4", "Branch": "AFL", "Date": "24/11/2013" },
    { "Vid": "3", "Receiptno": "AFL125", "Type": "6", "Branch": "AFL", "Date": "25/11/2013" },
];
```

I am passing it to DataTables like this:

```
$("#tblReceipt").dataTable({
    "aaData": JSON.stringify(r),
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [
      { "mData": "Vid" },
      { "mData": "Receiptno" },
      { "mData": "Type" },
      { "mData": "Branch" },
      { "mData": "Date" },
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
      "sProcessing": "Fetching Data, Please wait..."
    },
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you doing stringify for `aaData` ? Is `aaData` a string ?

Comment: Try to remove the last comma.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted since I posted a working demo that proves that the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `"aaData": JSON.stringify(r),` with `"aaData": r,`. 
*Working demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/qMPzh/1/